# swift - mini modal style wizard, working but visual effects looks wired

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a Storyboard project where I have my main `UINavigationController` and in a specific view controller I present this style wizard modal. The code for showing the modal when touching the "+" navigation button:

[image]

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let nc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("procedurenav") as! UINavigationController
    nc.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
    nc.navigationBarHidden = true
    self.presentViewController(nc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The result is this:

[image]

The modal is an UINavigationController that will handle my "wizard" style.

This is how it looks in my Storyboard (**I have added a View in the center of the controller and that area will be the one showing information**).

[image]

The problem happens exactly when I push the next wizard UIViewController, because you see how the new view is pushing all the screen and I just want to make visual effect that is pushing the center area that will be my wizard.

Here is the link of a gif animation of the issue (copy and paste the URL in a new tab)

http://g.recordit.co/d4AAAnFsZt.gif

This is the code that pushes views in my "wizard":

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("searchAuthorization") as! UIViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
```

> Any clue?

Comment: **the link of a gif animation** doesn´t work for me

Comment: copy the link and paste it to a new tab... thanks